# CSS issue in IE7

Tags: html, css

```
<style>

        div{
            height:100px;
                    }

        #wrapper{
            position:relative;
        }           

        #navigation {

            position:relative;
            width:400px;
            background-color:black;
            float:left;
        }
        #content{
            width:2300px;
            background-color:red;
            padding-left:500px;

        }

        #iframe{
            background-color:green;
        }


    </style>

<div id="wrapper">

        <div id="navigation">
            sss

        </div>

        <div id="content">

            <div id="iframe">
                content
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

In browsers like IE8,FF #content div is coming inline with navigation in IE 7 content div is coming down. 
I am looking for solution of this issue ine ie7 Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

had similar problem. got solved the issue thanks to user VinayC. I'm sure this will help u too. solution is relative positioning. check this link: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/position_relative_overflow_ie/

Answer (score 0):

In IE the `#content` is coming down because the width of that element is greater than the window/body. But I'm not sure if this is same with IE9.

To solve this add a width to the `#wrapper` that is greater than the width of `#navigaton` + `#content`.

```
#wrapper{
    position:relative;
    width: 2800;
}
```

Also why do you have such a long width and padding for the `#content`?

Comment: Not working in IE7 . Just wondering if this issue is related with hasLayout property

Comment: Try to add more width to the #wrapper like about width:3200px. This maybe because the padding of #content also needed to cover by #wrapper width. Its better see a working example here jsfiddle.net/a9Paq . If it still not solve the problem, I guess your actual code is not the same with your example and some CSS maybe affecting it.